# Flask extensions IN PyCharm

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

I'm actually having trouble using the `flask.ext` with PyCharm ide. I installed the flask-script and flask-bootstrap but the Pycharm is unable to recognize them. I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/brucewilson/PycharmProjects/demo_proj/demo.prj.py", line 5, in <module>
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
File "/home/brucewilson/flasky/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 87, in load_module
raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.bootstrap
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've installed the extensions in your virtualenv? And not accidentally installed them to global?

Comment: ya i activated the virtualenv and then did pip installflask-script.All other extensions that i installed are working except those related to flask.ext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to import Flask-Bootstrap is with

```
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
```

not with

```
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
```

As per the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html).

Comment: but it was given in a reknowned book as it is flask.ext.bootstrap

Comment: How old is the book? Can you at least try it and see if it works?

Comment: ya i tried it out it but it was producing this error anyways it worked..thnq.Is there any way i can find out such changes